# Databricks parallel mv files using dbutils.fs.mv

Tags: azure, databricks

I have azure storage account and have some files (more than millions of files) in a single folder .
I want to use dbutils.fs.mv to another folder . what's the fastest way to do that ?

Comment: I suppose [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) would be more suitable for your case.

Comment: @mytabi, any reason for to use only `dbutils.fs.mv`? any limitations that you have on other ways of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following methods.

1. [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) as suggested by @[Kombajn zbożowy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2890093/kombajn-zbo%c5%bcowy).

   Use the below sample code for that.

   ```
   azcopy copy "https://rakeshgen2.blob.core.windows.net/mysource2/<SAS Key>" "https://rakeshgen2.blob.core.windows.net/targetdata/<SAS Key>" --recursive=true
   ```

   [image]

   **Target files:**

   [image]

   You can go through this [link](https://nealanalytics.com/blog/what-is-the-best-way-to-transfer-huge-files-to-azure-data-lake-storage/) to know more about `azcopy` performance.
2. You can use `dbutils.fs.mv` or `dbutils.fs.cp` after mounting.

   **Example:**

   ```
   try:
      dbutils.fs.mv("/mnt/mysource2/","/mnt/targetadb",recurse=True)
   except:
      pass
   ```

   [image]
3. [Copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) may also work for you if there are no recursive folders in your structure.

   Go through the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#copy-performance-and-scalability-achievable-using-azure-data-factory-and-synapse-pipelines) to understand about copy activity performance and speed.